# Adding buffers around each city of user defined region using geopandas?

Tags: python, buffer, geopandas

How do I obtain a buffer around each city on the overlay map of cities on the United States area?

I have used the following piece of code to work this out but this does not work out it seems.

I am using `geopandas` in `python` to solve this:

```
 import pandas as pd
 import geopandas
 df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'City': ['Fargo', 'Orange', 'Jersey City'],
         'State': ['Nevada', 'California', 'New Jersey'],
         'Latitude': [46.877186 , 33.787914 , 40.728157 ],
         'Longitude': [-96.789803, -117.853104, -74.077644]})
    df['Coordinates']  = list(zip(df.Longitude, df.Latitude))
    df['Coordinates'] = df['Coordinates'].apply(Point)
    gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Coordinates')
    print(gdf.head())

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
#nybb=  geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('nybb'))
# We restrict to United States Of America.
us_name = world[world.name=='United States']
ax = world[world.name == 'United States'].plot(
    color='white', edgecolor='black',figsize=(20,10))
us_states.plot(ax=ax,figsize=(20,10))


# We can now plot our GeoDataFrame.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
ax.set(xlim=(-140,-50),ylim=(0,60))

gdf['Coordinates']=gdf.buffer(100)
gdf.plot()
gplot=geopandas.overlay(us_name,gdf,how='identity')
gplot.plot(edgecolor = 'k',alpha=0.5,cmap='tab10')
```

But what I want is buffers around each city on the map of the United States but what I get is just the map of US!

I am very new in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct, but you're plotting everything into different figures. Most plotting functions accept an `ax=` parameter, which you can set to your `ax` object:

```
# We can now plot our GeoDataFrame.
gdf.plot(ax=ax, color='red')
ax.set(xlim=(-140,-50), ylim=(0,60))

gdf['Coordinates'] = gdf.buffer(1.5)
gdf.plot(ax=ax)
gplot.plot(edgecolor='k', alpha=0.5, cmap='tab10', ax=ax)
```

Additionally, the buffer you're making is in degrees, not meters, so a buffer of 100° is enormously large. A quick way to get from meters to degrees is `m / 111139` though this might not always be what you want.